# Crosscompile Clion for Embeded Linux on ARM platform

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, cross-compiling, clion

I am newbie in Linux and Clion cross compile , I have a script in clion and build it to sh file for run in ubuntu 16.It runs complete but when I want run it on Debian, it dosent work and show "Cannot execute binary file". How i can run sh file or clion script in any Linux version?

Comment: My Linux run on Nanopi2 fire board

Comment: Do you have a compiler for `arm` architecture? Because `clion` normally takes whatever is defined by `CXX` and that might be `GNU c++`.

Comment: @hagard you need to add a toolchain to cmake, something like that https://github.com/taka-no-me/android-cmake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
After coding in Clion and save it in .cpp extension (or .c , .cc) only needs to compile it with an ARM gcc or g++ (for me arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++) and make binary file for ARM platform.Thanks to comments.

Comment: u can do same from command line , this doesn't solve the problem , the clion is useless in this solution